# res.render in callback is not executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following code:

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/../temp/temp.js', req.body.editor, (err) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log('file read');
    res.render('index', {
      instructions: reader.readInstructions('lesson1.txt'),
      console: 'hola maigos'
    })
  })
})
```

When the post request is sent, my browser sends an error saying localhost didnt send any data. The console.log is executed, but the render does not wok. If i take the res.render out of the fs.writeFile function it works as expected.

Why doesn't the res.render happen? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which templating engine are you using?

Comment: Are you sure that `err` is undefined? otherwise, you wouldn't be able to reach the `res.render` line because you are returning a `console.error`

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup your template engine correctly?

If so, check if your file is inside the directory set from the application setting properties:

```
app.set('views', './views') //here check if your index file is inside the views or the directory of your template folder
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
```

Source: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html